# Combining an Observable Array of Observable<boolean> to an Observable<boolean[]> - am I doing this right?

Tags: rxjs

Let's say I have an Observable list of Observable:

```
const a = [Observable.of(false), Observable.of(false)];
const aSbj: Observable<Array<Observable<boolean>>> = new BehaviorSubject(a);
```

I want to combine all the Observables inside a into a Observable of boolean[]. Here's my idea (using TypeScript):

```
const listObs = aSbj
    .switchMap((observables: Array<Observable<boolean>>) => {
      return Observable.combineLatest(...observables);
    });
```

This seems to work and is able to get me the results that I want, but my questions are:

1. Am I understanding switchMap correctly?
2. Does this create a new Observable everytime aSbj fires? Does this have any significant performance impacts?

---

(context:)

My ultimate goal is to map the entire list of boolean into an any() value:

```
const anyObs = listObs.map((booleans) => {
  return booleans.some(i => i)
});
```

... such that when I change aSbj, anyObs would emit the right value:

```
const any;
anyObs.subscribe((anyVal) => any = anyVal); // any == false
aSbj.next([Observable.of(true), Observable.of(false)]);
// any == true
```

Comment: If you just want to map a `boolean[]` to an _`any`_ value, the `boolean`s don't need to be `Observable` themselves. Any reason why they are? You could just do `bools$ = Observable.of([false,false,false]); any$ = bools$.map(arr => arr.some(b => b));`

Comment: I abstracted the question a little bit, but the Observable<boolean> is necessary. Imagine individual booleans represent a toggle state in a group of toggles, and their states change over time.

Comment: It still doesn't look like `Observable<boolean>` is right here. If the nth element in the array is the state of the nth toggle like it sounds, then push individual updates through their own subjects: `bool_subjects: Array<BehaviorSubject<bool>>`. Then `Observable.combineLatest(bool_subjects).map((bools) => bools.some(b => b))`.

Comment: @concat I didn't see your comment, and posted a very similar answer which goes through this case step-by-step.

Comment: @PeterZhang However when in your example, you trigger a change with `aSbj.next([Observable.of(true), ...`, you don't actually emit a new value on the previous `Observable<boolean>`, you just emit a new Observable. How does your real use case look like?

Comment: Right, sorry for brushing over a key detail. The array of boolean can be changing - aka, removing or adding new Observable<boolean> into the list. New boolean Observables can be added to the array and it should affect the final map value. Therefore, simply calling `combineLatest` on a list of boolean doesn't work. In the example usecase mentioned above, the group of toggles can have new toggles added or toggles removed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, I do not misinterpret your question. I think, there's one big issue with having a subject like that. Here's the code with line numbers:

```
(1) const source1 = Observable.of(false);
(2) const source2 = Observable.of(false);

(3) const independentObservables = [source1, source2];

(4) const subject: Observable<Observable<boolean>[]> =
(5)   new BehaviorSubject(independentObservables);
```

The issues is that `source1` and `source2` are normally created once and then *become "static streams"*. Meaning, as soon as they are passed to `Subject`, they will never be modified with other streams. Therefore, `Subject` may only produce an event once, which reflects the original values from `source1` and `source2`.

---

Instead of lines `(4), (5)`, what *in my understanding* should be done, is creation of a new observable which "listens" to all the independent observables. It may look like this (using [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)):

```
(6) const watchingObservable = Observable.combineLatest(...independentObservables);
```

And you use it to `map` (to produce an aggregated result) or `subscribe` directly:

```
(7) const aggregatedObservable: Observable<boolean> =
(8)   watchingObservable.map(values => values.some(Boolean));

(9) aggregatedObservable.subscribe( ... );
```

Comment: @peter-zhang does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it does miss one detail that I failed to elaborate on in my original question. Simply calling Observable.combineLatest on a static list of boolean Observables doensn't work, since the list can change over time.

Comment: @PeterZhang oh, boy. That is a completely different problem then! :( I even created a plunker about `combineLatest()` https://plnkr.co/edit/eQeRKHdF3Vm30EJ1raXh?p=preview